# Using Inline variables in command line commands

Tags: bash, shell

The command below repeats the word "stage" three times. Is there a way to set a variable at the beginning of the command and then use it further on?

```
AWS_REGION="us-west-2" AWS_PROFILE="stage" mvn clean test -Dtest=KarateRunner#stage -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=stage"
```

Something like:

```
set env=stage && AWS_REGION="us-west-2" AWS_PROFILE="%env%" mvn clean test -Dtest=KarateRunner#%env% -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=%env%"
```

But this doesn't work, obviously.

Comment: `"%env%"` this is not bash syntax.  `"${env}"` or `"$env"`  would be bash syntax.

Comment: Perhaps define a function that takes `stage` as an argument?

Comment: Setting such a variable in front of a command sets the value for the environment of the command. You can verify it with `foo=bar printenv foo`. In your case, you want to set the variable in the current shell. Hence they must be set in a separate statement (`foo=bar; echo $foo`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```bash
env=stage; AWS_REGION="us-west-2" AWS_PROFILE="$env" mvn clean test -Dtest="KarateRunner#$env" -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=$env"
```

You don't need testing boolean shell assignation:

```
env=stage && [...]
```

It will always return `true` as far of you assign a string or don't use a sub-command returning `false`.

Comment: Revision 2, explicitly specifying bash syntax highlighting, still was incorrectly highlighted in my (Chromium-based) browser. (direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78148123/2)

Comment: It should be noted that these alternatives are semantically different from the OP's in that they will leave the `env` variable set in the host shell.  The original command does not set any variables in the host shell.

Comment: OP can use a subshell if needed: `( x=foobar; echo ... )`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the variable.

```
env=stage && AWS_REGION="us-west-2" AWS_PROFILE="$env" mvn clean test "-Dtest=KarateRunner#$env" -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=$env"
```

Comment: @GillesQuénot there is no point

Comment: This does leave variable `env` set in the host environment after the `mvn` command terminates, which the original does not.